# Ordering in a select clause, to support many columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to select users from the users table based on:

```
user.created
user.sales_count
```

So I want to fetch all users, sometimes ordered by created date, and sometimes based on sales_count.  And I want to be able to switch between ASC or DESC order.

All queries need to have this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE region = 123
```

How can I build my active record query to support these order by conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_users(options={})
  options[:order_col] ||= "created"
  options[:order_type] ||= ""
  User.where(:region=>123).order("#{options[:order_col]} #{options[:order_type]}")
end
```

`options[:order_col] ||=` is really saying:

`options[:order_col] = options[:order_col] || ""`

which in english is saying set `options[:order_col]` to `options[:order_col]` if set, other wise `""`. We can set the order_type to `""` because SQL will by default order results ASC.

Example:

```
get_users #=> return ordered by created ASC
get_users(:order_col => "sales_count") #=> return order by sales count ASC
get_users(:order_col => "sales_count", :order_type => "DESC") #=> sales_count, DESC
# etc
```

Comment: doesn't this leave you open to sql injections though?